# Parse live stream HTTP chunked transfer JSON with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http, chunked

Here is live HTTP stream that delivers streaming JSON objects using chunked transfer encoding: http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps

Is it possible to parse this JSON request using jQuery getJSON ? I want to get each item as it comes in and insert new image tag with the image. Like the function I wrote below, but doesn't work

```
$.getJSON("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps", displayImages);
```

function displayImages(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(i,item) {

`$("<img/>").attr("src", item.member.photo).appendTo('#images');


});`

}

Comment: No it doesn't console saying: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain issue.

Comment: Any way to use JSONP to parse a streaming HTTP?

Comment: In JSONP server should returns javascript code not JSON data. Actually you cannot read from external site if the side does not provide JSONP interface.

Comment: What's more, even going direct to XMLHttpRequest without getJSON, it is not possible to read partial HTTP responses across all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make cross-domain ajax requests due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to sidestep the problem, but the web service needs to support it.

It looks like the [Meetup API supports JSONP](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/#callbacks), though naturally JSONP can't handle streaming-style updates.

Comment: Yeah, I looked this up, looks like "JSONP also has no support for streaming" - http://goo.gl/okjqH ?

Comment: I'm actually already using Meetup API for callbacks, my issue is that it doesn't seem to work with the HTTP streaming URL .. which is different to the normal JSON requests hmm

Comment: That is correct. JSONP works by passing a well-formed piece of JSON to a callback function. With streaming JSON, how do you know when it's ready to be passed to a callback function?

Comment: For streaming over HTTP see: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: The typical streaming JSON output format is newline-separated list of well-formed JSON-formatted objects, but the entire document is not actually well-formed JSON. There's just no way to reconcile that when using JSONP.

Comment: @Taha: Comet isn't useful to the OP here since the Meetup API doesn't provide a Comet interface.