# Parsing stuck-together json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, comet

I'm looking at a json that looks like this

```
{
    "key": "cow",
    "value": "woof"
}
{   
    "key": "dog",
    "value": "moo"
}
```

And i wan to parse it, but JSON.parse doesn't work because the thing as a whole isn't *really* json. There actually aren't any newlines either, so it looks like

```
{"key": "cow","value": "woof"}{"key": "dog","value": "moo"}
```

As to the *why*, this is the stream coming from a Comet endpoint. Ideally it should come one by one, but sometimes there's an interruption, and after it comes back i receive the list of all changes that have happened since the interruption happened, strung together. So if three dicts were meant to have come down while the connection was broken, i'll get them all at once at the end:

```
{"key": "cow","value": "woof"}{"key": "dog","value": "moo"}{"key":"cat","value":"baaa"}
```

Is there any convenient way of parsing this kind of json in the browser?

EDIT: Sorry guys, i didn't mention that the objects can be arbitrarily nested and can contain all sorts of things, Unicode characters, arrays, objects, arrays with objects, braces of all shapes and sizes, etc. etc. so most hacky string-split or regex solutions will fail in these cases. I didn't put any of these in the examples because i was being lazy, but a more representative example may be

```
{
    "key": "cow",
    "value": {
        "body": "big",
        "name": "sally",
        "children": [
            "bob",
            "daisy"
        ]
    },
    "alt-key": "牛"
}
{   
    "key": "dog",
    "value": "moo{}{}{}}}} i love brackets[[[]] ]]]]      }{}",
    "array": [
        "豆沙包",
        "叉烧包"
    ]
}
```

Although a regex/stringsplit thing would work 95% of the time, I'm looking for a strictly correct solution that'll always work when fed correct json

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse the first JSON object on a stream in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829811/how-can-i-parse-the-first-json-object-on-a-stream-in-js) or [Parse live stream HTTP chunked transfer JSON with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5927932/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd just write a JSON parser that understands a stream of JSON expressions. JSON is about as easy to parse as grammars get, and making a parser that's able to "reset" itself for a new sentence is a simple (once the parser exists).

Heck you could start from the json.org parser itself.

To reliably "fix" your current data is a project that comes really close to writing a parser anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If values and keys won't contain `}{`, you could simply add commas to make it valid JSON (and add square brackets to make it an array):

```
var json = '[' + json.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']';
```

This would even work if you only get a single object as response.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = flowstring.match(/{.*?}/g).map(function(value){
    return JSON.parse(value);
});
```

and you will have this array of objects:

```
[{"key": "cow","value": "woof"},{"key": "dog","value": "moo"}.......]
```

Comment: Woah, that's pretty clever :-)

Comment: Note that this only works if objects are not nested and strings cannot contain `}`.

Comment: @Charmander It's obvious from question, that objects can't be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting that to an array, then parse that.  Something like this:

```
var json = '{"key": "cow","value": "woof"}{"key": "dog","value": "moo"}';
var newjson = '[' + json.replace(/\}\{/g, '},{') + ']';
var obj = JSON.parse(newjson);
```